# Add checkbox to each ItemTemplate value

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater, datalist, itemtemplate

I am binding a List with a size of 5 to a `DataList` with this code:

```
 <ItemTemplate>
     <%# Eval("Id") %>
     <%# Eval("FirstName") %>
     <%# Eval("LastName") %>
     <%# Eval("City") %>
 </ItemTemplate>
```

I would like to add dynamically via code behind a checkbox next to every 5 list items and next to every itemtemplate eval property (Id, FirstName, LastName, City).

I would like to have an output like this (on the ASPX page):

```
(X)1 (X)Mike (X)A (X)New York

(X)2 (X)John (X)B (X)New York

(X)3 (X)Kevin (X)C (X)New York

(X)4 (X)Oswald (X)D (X)New York

(X)5 (X)Rene (X)E (X)New York
```

**(X) = checkbox**

Those checkboxes should have an own unique id.

Can you guys give me some tips on how to do this or redirect me to good sources? I couldn't find anything via Google.

My output at the moment is:

```
1 Mike A New York

2 John B New York

3 Kevin C New York

4 Oswald D New York

5 Rene E New York
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
Use: <ItemTemplate>
<asp:CheckBox ID="iDCheckbox" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Id") %>'/>                                 
        ...etc...                        
</ItemTemplate>
```

set Display="inline" if it defaults to blockset Display="inline" if it defaults to block

Comment: Show your complete codebehind giving what you show as the results.  No reason you can't create the checkboxes in codebehind around those eval functions you have there, within those item templates